# Python pypi upload with twine retruns error: ItemNotFoundException: Item does not exist

Tags: python, pypi, python-packaging, twine

I could not find any relevant content here or elsewhere about this issue.

I am basically trying to upload a new version of my package to PyPi, and I get this strange error:

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
# this works fine

twine upload dist/*
# returns:
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your username: XXXXXXXXXX
ItemNotFoundException: Item does not exist!
```

I could not find any reference to this error, and the exception is not even in twine source code.

I can confirm that both package and my user account are fine in pypi.org.

Any ideas why I am having this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Raised the issue directly to the app github: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer documented in GitHub: https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/383

Basically, the error thrown is not part of the twine package. Solved with D-Bus/keyring installation (which was not installed as dependency package from twine).